# __SECRET_DOM_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED when porting in SharePoint 2010

Tags: html, reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have an HTML page done by an external company.
I deployed it in SharePoint 2010 as normal HTML page and it works.
Instead importing the same code in a SharePoint 2010 aspx page using a Page Viewer I get the error in the subject.
It seems becouse ReactJS is not initialized well.

How to avoid this issue?

Comment: When you say you "get the error in the subject" what exactly do you mean? Where do you see the error? Please be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end we found that the master page of SharePoint forces IE compability to 8.

To resolve I added this code in code behind Page_Load event:

```
            HtmlMeta metaEdgeIE = new HtmlMeta();
            metaEdgeIE.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
            metaEdgeIE.Content = "IE=11";
            Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, metaEdgeIE);
```

Thank you anyway